# Hiding a scrollable Header (HTML ID)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Im using a template and working with it because my html / css skills arent really existing.

On my Website:

http://s526367159.online.de/reclaim/website/startseite/

you can see a white stripe after you scroll a bit. This comes from a "scrollable" header. I could delete the background and disable the logo by changing it with a 1px .png file. I found some of the options in the wordpress settings for thsi template but i couldnt realy disable it.

While checking it out with chrome i found this:

```
<header id="header" class="wide is-sticky">
<div class="header-content" id="header-content">        
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://s526367159.online.de/reclaim/website" title="Reclaim – Blackhand">
                <img src="http://s526367159.online.de/reclaim/website/wp-content/themes/elite/assets/img/placeholder/logo-white.png" alt="" class="logo-start">
                <img src="http://s526367159.online.de/reclaim/website/wp-content/themes/elite/assets/img/placeholder/logo.png" alt="" class="logo-scroll">                  
            </a>
        </div>

        <nav id="header-menu">
                        </nav>

        <a href="#" id="menu-mobile-trigger"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="header-mobile" style="display: none;">
    <div class="container">     
        <nav id="header-menu-mobile">
                        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is basicly the header. Could one of you please tell me how i can disable this whole stuff? I just need a website title. I can remember that there is a hide function in css. I guess it is possible to hide html objects by ID or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS would be :

```
#header.wide {
    display:none;
}
```

The problem is, Javascript is controlling its opacity.  Looking into it.

Comment: actually that did work quite fine. Couldnt find anything that did crash or something like that. Thanks!